# MySQL Row Isn't Found But It's There

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm using PHP to try and select a single row from a table in my MySQL database. I've run the query manually inside phpMyAdmin4 and it returned the expected results. However, when I run the EXACT same query in PHP, it's returning nothing.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE username=".$username." and charactername=".$characterName."";
if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
        while($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            echo $row[0];    
        }
        $result->close();
}
else
        echo "No results for username ".$username." for character ".$characterName.".";
```

And when I test this in browser I get the "No results..." echoed back. Am I doing something wrong?

This isn't a duplicate question because I'm not asking when to use certain quotes and backticks. I'm asking for help on why my query isn't working. Quotes just happened to be incorrect, but even when corrected the problem isn't solved. Below is the edited code as well as the rest of it. I have removed my server information for obvious reasons.

```
<?PHP
$username = $_GET['username'];
$characterName = $_GET['characterName'];

$mysqli = new mysqli("REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `characters` WHERE `username`='".$username."' and `charactername`='".$characterName."'";

if($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
        while($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
            echo $row[0];    
        }

        $result->close();
}
else
        echo "No results for username ".$username." for character ".$characterName.".";

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: strings? `WHERE username=".$username." and charactername=".$characterName."";` - pretty sure they are.

Comment: How do you know that you're running the exact same query? I don't see you printing it out

Comment: yeah, you need to wrap the `SQL` variable values in single quotes.

Comment: check for errors on your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: you're also open to an SQL injection if those variables are coming from user-input.

Comment: @Joni I haven't posted my full code here, but believe you me, I know for a fact they're the same query. I've tested it several times.

Comment: @OliverQueen have fixed the single quotes but the problem persists.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have fixed the single quotes but the problem persists. And I'm aware of the risk of injection.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII you need single quotes around the double quotes

Comment: @DavidRosenIII Hi David. Could you update your question then and with the new code you are now using, ***however,*** please don't overwrite your originally posted code, but post your new code under your old code and marked as an edit. Plus, you should also be posting any other relevant code as to where those variables are coming from, as well as the db schema and db connection used.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII you went and overwrote your original question. and the person who posted an answer for it, may get downvoted for it. Please rollback and mark it as an edit. thank you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Okay. I hope I did it right this time. I don't want anyone receiving  down votes for my mistake.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($mysqli))` to `mysqli_query()`. I suspect that your GETs may be failing you. Are you using a form? is it using a GET or POST method? that is unclear as to where they are coming from and if from a form, name attributes to match.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII I think I know why it's failing: `$mysqli = new mysqli("REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED");` you didn't choose a database. If so, and your password isn't required, you still need an empty parameter for it. I.e.: `$mysqli = new mysqli("host","user", "", "db");`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yep. That was exactly it. After I added the `or die(mysqli_error($mysql))` it informed me that I had no database selected. Then I noticed I deleted my `mysqli_select_db` line. x_x Thanks for the help. I put the db selection back, and it's working properly now.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII I posted my answer below David. and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing: `$mysqli = new mysqli("REDACTED","REDACTED","REDACTED");` because you didn't choose a database.

Connecting to a database using the MySQLi API requires 4 parameters:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

If your password isn't required, you still need an (empty) parameter for it.

I.e.: `$mysqli = new mysqli("host","user", "", "db");`

Plus, as noted.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**`mysqli_*` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

---

**Footnotes:**

As stated in the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/35635439/1). Strings require to be quoted in values.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll definitely be looking into prepared statements once I'm done getting the basic structure up and running, and before the game goes live.

Comment: @DavidRosenIII You're most welcome David, I was glad to have helped, *cheers!*

Answer (score 0):

You need to add quotes to the strings in your query:

```
$query = "SELECT * 
    FROM characters 
    WHERE username='".$username."' and charactername='".$characterName."'";
```

Comment: Still getting the same results.